# Match array key with a string then add a function to the key value - php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to compare a string with an array key and if they match, I want to call a function to replace the value of the matched key.

**my array:**

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => Ahmed [name] => Ahmed Jalal [avatar] => no_avatar.png )
```

my function:

```
resizer($avatar,'50');
```

**and I'm using this cod to do the job**

```
$query = $db->prepare($mysql);
$db->stmt_assoc($query, $table);
$query->fetch();
if ($table['avatar']) {
$data[] = call_user_func('resizer', $table['avatar'],'50');
$table['avatar']=$data;
}
if($type == 'json'){
return json_encode($data);
}else{
return $table;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how my question doesn't make sense to you alexender! you edit is absolutely not in a place. If you don't get the question read it again please.

Comment: `unset($avatar);` This probably won't work because you have to specify  the key within the array variable. Could you explain more on what the above code is doing/should do?

Comment: I'm trying to go through each key of a php array and match that key with a string let's say "avatar" for the string. then add a php function to the "avatar" key value something and then modify the value of the avatar key with the php function which is specifically used for that key

Comment: If `$table` is an array, have you tried `foreach()`? Previously, I was confused you are looping through a resultset from the DB. Also, unsetting the array key and then passing the value would not work, you probably want to do it, after you have passed the value.

Comment: even when I try foreach(), I can't seem to find a solution, especially when I'm using php v.5.2

Comment: check out my approach that I added to the question, maybe you have a clearer picture.

Comment: If this is a 2d array then `avatar` will be mentioned just once, in that case, you don't need the loop and `$data = resizer($table['avatar'],'50');` will work.

Comment: I'm sorry, the array does have more stuff in it, I should've mention that. and it's just one array. avatar also vary, not always the same position in the array. I tried to use key number with array_keys() function. it works but not idea, cuz it won't work always

Comment: Could you please paste a sample of the original array? Depending on the nested level, loops may vary.

Comment: array ( [username] => somename [name] => somefullname [avatar] => no_avatar.png )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52492/discussion-between-i-can-has-kittenz-and-mustafa-m-jalal)

Comment: use foreach($array as $key => $val) then compare $key to the string. f it's what you want the $$key = create_function('', '$key = $val; return $val'); call it by the name of the key so avatar would be avatar();

Comment: now if i do that, can I call my resizer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry for my misunderstanding so here is some code based off the array you gave. It will turn each key into the name of a variable and store the value of that key in the named variable.

```
$g['id'] = 1;
$g['username'] = 'Ahmed';
$g['name'] = 'Ahmed Jalal';
$g['avatar'] = 'no_avatar.png';

foreach($g as $k => $v)
{
    $$k = $v;
}

echo $avatar; // displays no_avatar.png
```

Yes you can use resize if you include the path to the image in avatar or in a new array key while using gd or imagemagick or another gfx addition to php.